# Differentiate between source address of udp packets

Tags: nginx, configuration, nginx-reverse-proxy

I currently have an nginx instance that listens on port 8000 for udp traffic, and then sends the packet to a server listening on port 5678. I was asked to reconfigure my nginx such that depending on who (ip and port of sender) sent the packet to port 8000, the packet will be sent to the corresponding server. For example, if process one is on localhost:1234 and sends a udp to port 8000, nginx will forward this to server one. If process two, on localhost:2345, sends a udp to port 8000 nginx will forward that packet to server 2. Is this possible? Here is my config file.

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}


stream {
        server {
                listen  127.0.0.1:8000 udp;
                proxy_pass      127.0.0.1:5678;
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it by using a map. Updated config is now

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}


stream {
        #define the various upstreams
        upstream app_1 {
                server 127.0.0.1:5678;
        }

        upstream app_2 {
                server 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
        #map source port to upstream
        map $remote_port $backend_svr {
                1234 "app_1";
                1235 "app_2";
        }
        #all udp traffic received on 8000, depending on source it will be redirected
        server {
                listen 8000 udp;
                proxy_pass $backend_svr;
        }

}
```